# My ubuntu on PC boots to a black screen, after installing firmware-b43-installer

Tags: boot, drivers, screen

I wanted to make a hotspot and to solve a problem I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

and rebooted the machine to see the effects, but I got a black screen, I can hear the drum sound prompting me to log in. I think the OS boots successfully but with a black screen. My ubuntu was 16.04, after this issue, I took that into recovery mode and upgraded it to 18.04, but the problem's not solved.
I read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and some other posts but they didn't help me. Also I set `nomodeset` in Grub but I couldn't fix the main problem. So, my question is; how can I fix the black screen. I'm not very good at Linux.
Any suggestions are welcome and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has fixed using the following page:

**[How to Fix Display Problems on Ubuntu](https://lockergnome.com/2011/07/05/how-to-fix-display-problem-ubuntu/)**

Thanks a lot her/him.